# How do I tell apart voiced and unvoiced plosives after a stop with no audible release?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm making a conlang and I want it to differentiate voiced, breathy voiced, unvoiced, and unvoiced aspirated plosives, but I'm having trouble telling apart the pronunciation of voiced/unvoiced when it comes after a stop without audible release.

Ex:

[mat̚ da] vs. [mat̚ ta]
or [mat̚ dʱa] vs. [mat̚ tʰa]

Comment: That’s not usually an issue in languages where such sequences are possible. English only distinguishes (optionally) voiced from voiceless aspirated, so not the best example, but there’s no difficulty in distinguish ‘what beach?’ from ‘what peach?’. Thai similarly has no trouble distinguishing [mat̚ da], [mat̚ ta] and [mat̚ tʰa]. The real difficulty is in distinguishing these sounds in the _first_ part of the cluster: [mat̚ ta], [mad̚ ta], mad̚ʰ ta] and [mat̚ʰ ta] are much harder to distinguish clearly (the latter two are arguably not possible to produce at all).